# Azure function with Azure Active Directory aad failed with incorrect reply url

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to secure the Azure functions using Azure Active Directory following the [note](https://medium.com/medialesson/protecting-azure-function-apps-with-azure-ad-authentication-authorization-fd167ce4fe33).

When the link `https://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net/api/function1` is entered, the browser redirects to AAD:

> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenent]/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=[client_id]&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=[nonce]state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252Ffunction1](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5Btenent%5D/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=%5Bclient_id%5D&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=%5Bnonce%5Dstate=redir%3D%252Fapi%252Ffunction1)

and the error returns:

> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

[image]

The platform configurations in the AAD client:

[image]

The Authentication & Authorization in Azure function `xxxfuntion1` is configured to AzureAD client `xxxfunction1app`:

[image]

The same error with Advanced mode:

[image]

Any idea why it says the error on the reply URL please?

Comment: Have you checked the Redirect URI in your App config file?

Comment: No app config. Currently I am run https://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net/api/function1 from Chrome.

Comment: It seems the URL in the portal is correct. I will try to follow the link to reproduce the error later.

Comment: Hi @beewest,Please remove dot  before auth in the url(i.e.,/.auth) of both app registration and code.Then please let us know the update

Comment: removed . in /.auth but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is very simple. Your redirect_uri is decoded as: `https://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`, but you configure the redirect_uri in the AAD client as:`https://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callcack`, so the response url does not match error, you only need to change `callcack` to `callback`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the URL matches exactly and double-check that the Application ID and tenant ID are matching. It might be trying to resolve to a different application or tenant.

The identifier URI should be: https://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net

Please go to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App Registration > All Applications > Search with the App ID 6419ae-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx > Under Authentication blade of the application update the Redirect URI to ttps://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net/api/function1

Comment: Added https://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net/api/function1, https://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net, https://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback, https://xxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net/auth/login/aad/callback to Web Platform configurations Redirect URLs. None of them is working. The AAD url is still https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant]/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxfunction1.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&...